# Syntax error in Javascript pattern

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching

I'm getting a syntax error in this simple javascript code. I just want to check the atring on a pattern. Can any one tell me what is wrong?

```
var a = 'test@server.com';
var pattern = [a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.[a-zA-Z0-9]+]*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.[a-zA-Z]+]+;
console.log('The comparison is ',a.match(pattern));
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your pattern is not a regular expression. It is just a bunch of characters and it will create a syntax error. Regular expressions literals start and end with `/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
var pattern = /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.[a-zA-Z0-9]+]*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.[a-zA-Z]+]+/;
```

Patterns are usually delimited by `//`. See [RegExp on MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/regexp).

Comment: Yeah, with "/" the syntax error disapperas, the strange thing is that matches return null. I think it should match the pattern

Comment: check the usage of the square brackets `[` and `]`... it is strange... I guess you want to have `[.a-zA-Z0-9]` instead of `[.[a-zA-Z0-9]+]` . But you should also be aware that the correct regexp for an email address is even more complex. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses for more details. BTW: `/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.a-zA-Z0-9]*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.a-zA-Z]+/` matches...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 var pattern = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.[a-zA-Z0-9]+]*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.[a-zA-Z]+]+$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have no delimiter on the pattern. Have you tried

```
var pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.[a-zA-Z0-9]+]*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[.[a-zA-Z]+]+';
```

?